# why adding 1.00 , 2.00 always gives me 3.0 in clojure?

Tags: clojure, decimal, addition

i don't know if thats a problem or the way it is, but i need a value with 2 decimal places. I can write a function to round it 2 decimal places, but is there a solution where in clojure itself handles it while adding. i mean by changing data type or something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clojure uses java's standard Double precision floating point numbers under the hood (as of 1.3) and the REPL only prints as many digits as it needs to to represent the number so in this case it is geting 3.0000000 ... but dropping the unnecessary digits.

you can control the number printed with the handy [format](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/format) function.

```
(format "%.2f" (+ 1.0 2.0))
> "3.00"
```

Comment: the format function will solve it there as well. it's the P re REPL that is Printing it with too few digits. the link in this answer covers lots of ways to get numbers formated to suit most needs.

Comment: but that does't solve my problem.. i don't want a function call here... but thanks for your quick replay..

Comment: in noir, when you pass a number in the response map, that map gets converted into a string as part of the final reply using the default print function, If you want your formatting used instead of the default then using a string may be the only viable answer.

Comment: @ Arthur Ulfeldt .. i just did that.. it seems to work.. but there a 100 such response maps where in i got do the same thing.. its really painfull..

Comment: @Sandy :You can implement a Ring middleware function to do that at one place

Answer (score 5):

`3.0` is equals `3.00` in clojure, is a double, if you want ouput a str with 2 decimal places, you can use format.

```
user> (= 3.0 3.00)
true
user> (== 3.0 3.00)
true
user> (format "%.2f" 3.0)
"3.00"
user> (class 3.00)
java.lang.Double
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do exact decimal arithmetic you can write the numbers with an 'M' suffix to indicate they are exact:

```
user=> (+ 1.00M 2.00M)
3.00M
```

But beware, this is much less efficient than using the standard inexact floating point numbers.